# OpenCV removing face from face recognizer model

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am developing simple app using openCV face recognition for user authentication. I've decided to use LBPH algorithm since it doesn't require recreating model each time after adding new faces, hence they don't need to be stored.

Unfotunately I cannot find any way to remove faces from model when user decides to delete account. It may generate problems if user deletes account and then signs in again. Is there any way for removing face from model, for example by editing yaml file where model is saved? Or should I just check if face is already stored in model during registration?

Comment: No. There is not un train method. And if you `update` the recognizer with same label and new image, it will just associate one more image to that label. There is no UNTRAIN feature in OpenCV.